# python wrong file format cause unpack error

Tags: python

When I use the python code below to deal with `right.txt` and `wrong.txt`, though they look totally the same, `wrong.txt` cannot be run. Is it the indent problem?

My code is here:

```
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('wrong.txt') as fin:
        text = fin.read()
    l = [p for p in text.split('\nSentence #') if p]
    for p in l:
        lines, deps = tuple(p.split('\n\n')[:2])
```

right.txt:

```
Sentence #1 (33 tokens):
introduction.
[Text=. CharacterOffsetBegin=208 CharacterOffsetEnd=209 PartOfSpeech=. Lemma=.] 
(ROOT

   (. .)))

root(ROOT-0, stored-18)
```

wrong.txt:

```
Sentence #1 (33 tokens):
introduction.
[Text=. CharacterOffsetBegin=208 CharacterOffsetEnd=209 PartOfSpeech=. Lemma=.] 
(ROOT

    (. .)))

root(ROOT-0, stored-18)
```

Comment: Why not paste your file contents right *here*?

Comment: It's too long. I've provided a link, can it be opened?

Comment: Provide a *relevant* section of the files (probably both); just a few lines from each may show the difference.

Comment: The link failed the first few times, then lead me to some website that I've never heard of and shows (after an extra click) two files each of about 470KB. That is generally too much effort to get your data (compared to my above suggestion), plus those files are way too large that I'm willing to try them out with your code.

Comment: "cannot be run.". What does that mean? Do you get an error? If so, please post the error. If not, please indicate what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I've provide a link of the file, can it be opened?

Comment: OK， I will post the file as soon as possible.

Comment: @SijiaXiao your question shouldn't link to external sites. It should contain all required information in itself

Comment: Try to reduce the files to as small as possible but still with the problem.

Comment: I've upload right.txt and wrong.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a compare of the two txt files, and found the (4111)differeces are all line endings (new Line). right.txt uses (0x0a, '\n'); wrong.txt uses (0x0d0a, '\r\n').

With above in mind, code could be something like this:

```
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('wrong.txt') as fin:
        text = fin.read()
    ending = '\r\n' if '\r\n' in text else '\n'
    l = [p for p in text.split( ending + 'Sentence #') if p]
    for p in l:
        lines, deps = tuple(p.split( ending * 2 )[:2])
```